# UK Cooling off period for long term visa while going back on valid visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I am currently on long term ICT visa in UK which is valid till Feb 2021 but i am going back in March 2020 so when will my cooling off period will start? Once validity will end or straight away as soon as i go back.

Please note that i didn’t finish my 5 year long term visa and my company applied only for 3 years and out of which i am going back within 2 years.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What type of ICT visa do you have and what do you mean by ‘cooling off’ period? Travel date? Leave date? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/836921/2019.06.05_-_MAAP_guidance_FINAL1.pdf#page49

Comment: I am on ICT tier 2 visa where you can switch the job. By cooling off period i mean the period where i can not travel again to UK.

Comment: Do you mean as a visitor?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this before, No actually on ICT tier 2 again. UK has entry restrictions to apply same visa for 1 year but since i am leaving before visa validity so when will that restriction will start for me? As soon as i leave or once validity will end. I hope this clarifies my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cooling off period is [described by UKVI](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/846380/tier-2-v34.0ext.pdf) as follows:

> If the application is for entry clearance or switching from another leave category within the UK, a 12-month cooling off period applies.
>
> The applicant must not have been in the UK with entry clearance or leave to remain as a Tier 2 migrant at any time during the 12 months immediately before the date of the application, unless one of the exceptions below applies.
>
> **Where the applicant left the UK before their Tier 2 leave expired**, the 12-month period can start earlier than the date their leave expired but only if they can provide evidence of having not been in the UK for a period of 12 months immediately before that date. Acceptable evidence may include, but is not limited to:
>
> - travel tickets or boarding cards or passes (in paper or electronic form), but only if the applicant’s sponsor submitted a Sponsorship Management System (SMS) report at the time, confirming that their employment in the UK had ended
> - exit or entry stamps in the applicant’s passport which confirms that they were not in the UK
> - a letter from the applicant’s overseas employer confirming the date they started or restarted work overseas, after returning from the UK
> - any other evidence that shows the applicant was not in the UK

So you should ensure that your employer informs UKVI promptly about the end of your employment in the UK, and that you save any other evidence you have of having left the UK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps.